# nginx: redirect to two different servers based on domain

Tags: nginx

Let's say I have a domain: mike.com.

I'd like to have `mike.com` and `www.mike.com` hit my nginx server and get served a page sitting at 123.1.1.1.

I'd like to have `api.mike.com` get served by a server sitting at 123.2.2.2.

Perhaps my google-fu is failing me in epic fashion, but how would I go about arranging such a setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 2 server blocks and `proxy_pass` to the appropriate backend server.

Try with this example:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         mike.com www.mike.com;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://123.1.1.1:8080;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         api.mike.com;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://123.2.2.2:8080;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```